# sqlalchemy custom type get original raw value?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I am using `JSONEncodedDict` found here

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#marshal-json-strings

If I want to access original JSON string from db directly without `process_result_value` is there any hidden attribute I can access instead of `json.dumps` the dict again?

Comment: Why do you need to use the `JSONEncodedDict` if you need a raw value? In any event, you can call `json.dumps(value)` again to get it.

Comment: @van Because 99% of the time I use it like a `dict`  for partial updates, but in certain places I want dump **the original value** for inspection. It's best if frontend renders exactly what's inside DB for possible corruption of data. e.g. varchar truncates values that's too long.